# Refresh or Close wpf window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a wpf window that shows Bing map whith som bushpin on it, 
The window is getting opened by button click in code behind.
Each time i click on the button, new window shows up with current new data.

How can i close the "allready" opened window and open the a new one with the new data, or maybe refresh the current opened window with the new data.

here is my code:

```
        IList<object> rowsToExport = getRows();
        BingMapWindow window = new BingMapWindow(rowsToExport);

        // somthing like this
        if(window.IsOpened)
           window.Close;
        window.show();

          OR
         if(window.IsOpened)
           window.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing reference to that window outside method and just checking it for null?

```
BingMapWindow window;

private void CloseWindow() 
{
    if(window != null)
    {
        window.Close();
        window = null;
    }
}

private void OpenWindow(BingMapWindow window)
{
    this.window = window;
    this.window.Show();
}

private void ButtonHandler()
{
    CloseWindow();
    var bingWindow = new BingMapWindow();
    OpenWindow(bingWindow);
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to 'refresh data', it may be enough if you change "DataContext" property if it's utilizing one.